# A version of Taylor's theorem in normed space from Zorich's Mathematical Analysis 10.6

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I am reading the Volume II of *Mathematical Analysis* written by Vladimir A. Zorich. I feel difficulty when trying to do the first excercise of Section 10, $\S$6 at Page 95.

**Theorem**: Let $X$, $Y$ be normed spaces.
Mapping $f \in C^{(n)}(U; Y)$ where $U$ is an open set in $X$. $x$ and $x + h$ are two points in $U$.

If $f$ is $(n+1)$-th differentiable in an interval $(x, x + h) := \{x + t h \mid t \in (0, 1)_\mathbb R\} \subset U$, and $\forall \xi \in (x, x + h)$, $\|f^{(n+1}(\xi)\| < M$, then:
$$
\left\|
f(x + h) - \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{n!} f^{(n)}(x) h^n\right\|_Y \leq \frac{M}{(n+1)!}\|h\|_X^{n+1}.
$$

Zorich divided the excercise into four parts and the first part defines a function $g \colon [0, 1]_\mathbb R \to Y$:
$$
g(t) := f(x + th) - \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{n!} f^{(n)}(x) (th)^n,
$$
and asked the reader to prove that $\|g'(t)\| \leq M \|t h\|_X^n \|h\|_X / n!$.

**My trial**: The derivative of $g$ is like:
$$
g'(t) = f'(x + th) h - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k!} f^{(k + 1)}(x)(th)^k h,
$$
which can be understood as a linear operator operates on $h$. I don't know what to do next.

Once the first part is proved, we can applied it to $g(1) - g(0)$ making use of finite-increment theorem so that $\|g(1) - g(0)\|_Y \leq M \|h\|_X^n \|h\|_X / n!$ and the theorem is almost proved.

**About notation**: (I don't know if Zorich's notation is familiar)
The $n$-th derivative of a function is a boundary, symmetric $n$-linear operators from $X$ to $Y$, $f^{(n)}(x) h_1 h_2 \cdots h_n$ and if $h_1 = \cdots = h_n = h$, we can write $f^{(n)}(x) h^n$.

Comment: I think if we define $g(t)$ by $g(t) = f(x) - f(x + t h) - f'(x + th) (-th) - f''(x + th) (-th)^2 / 2 + ...$ would be easier. The original question is too difficult for me...